# PHP variables in mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Im using mysql with PHP, I was just wondering if this query,

> $query = "UPDATE tblName SET field='$fieldValue' WHERE field2='$fieldValue2'"

would cause an Out of Memory Error in mysql. Will this query,

> $query = "UPDATE tblName SET field='".$fieldValue."' WHERE field2='".$fieldValue2."'"

consume less memory than the previous one?

Im getting this error: Out of memory (Needed nnnnnnn bytes) and its pointing to the query with the same format as the first one above.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but just a good advice: Never use `$var = "Text $var text";`. That's so utterly bad and horribly programming style my eyes keep on popping out every time I see it. It is safer and even easier to maintain code that is always properly escaped. Just because you can do it doesn't mean it's good style. So for the love of god: Escape your variables! ALWAYS!

Comment: oh.. thanks for the programming tip. ill try to remember it next time.

Comment: ApoY2k, you're massively over-exaggerating. Sure, escape user input, but saying `$var = "Text $var text";` is terrible is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as MySQL is concerned, the two strings are the same.

How big are these values in `$fieldValue` and `$fieldValue2`? If they're multiple megabytes, attempting to allocate space for the `$query` variable may be exceeding your PHP memory limit - perhaps you need to up it if you're working with large data.

Comment: The values for $fieldValue and $fieldValue2 are not big. Not yet anyway. Anyways thanks, ill try increasing the limit

Answer (score 1):

If you code like that, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/1624216#1624216) will happen. Don´t code like that, please.

Comment: The code posted doesn't indicate where the field values are coming from - it's quite possible that the values in the variables have already been properly pre-processed for validation+escaping.

Comment: Could be, but not likely. Call it a hunch ^^

Comment: @Dav No, even in that case you are wrong. Use prepared statements. Whatever you do, just do not use string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Both strings are the same, one uses inline interpolation, the other uses string concatenation. I think your problem has to be found somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Well the out of memory error is probably caused by the fact that the values in those variables are simply too long. If that is the case you should look into prepared statements as those can handle MUCH bigger values than simple queries.